# Migrating from existing dynamic web project to gradle?

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, gradle

I have a following structure .

[image]

I am constructing build.gradle by copy-paste from numerous sources..

```
 buildscript {
     repositories {
         jcenter()
         mavenCentral()
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.2.2'
     }

 }

 apply plugin: 'java'
 apply plugin: 'eclipse'
 apply plugin: 'idea'
 apply plugin: 'war'
 apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'

 webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

 repositories {
         jcenter()
     mavenCentral()
 }

 sourceSets {
 main {
 // where does the Java source code live?
 java {
 srcDir 'src'
 }

 // where do classpath resources like *.properties files live?
 resources {
 srcDir 'src/main/resources'
 }
}
 }


 sourceCompatibility = 1.7
 targetCompatibility = 1.7

 dependencies {
     testCompile("junit:junit")
     compile fileTree(dir: 'WebContent/WEB-INF/lib', include: ['*.jar'])
     String tomcatVersion = '7.0.52'
     tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}"
     tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}"
     tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}") {
         exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', module: 'ecj'
     }
 }

 task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
     gradleVersion = '2.3'
 }

 tomcat {
        contextPath = '/'
 }
```

when I run `gradle tomcatRun`, I see the following output

> 02:49:58.819 [QUIET]
>   [com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.embedded.BaseTomcatServerImpl$AfterStartEventLifecycleListener]
>   Started Tomcat Server 02:49:58.820 [QUIET]
>   [com.bmuschko.gradle.tomcat.embedded.BaseTomcatServerImpl$AfterStartEventLifecycleListener]
>   The Server is running at http://localhost:8080
>
> > Building 75% > :tomcatRun

But when I connect to http://localhost:8080 I see either 404 error or blank page..

Comment: It means the Tomcat server runs but your web application is not picked up. First check the paths. In build file you provided wrong paths for `srcDir` for both java and resources.

Comment: I have ` ${proj_root}/src/main/java ${proj_root}/src/main/resources` how should I change mine?

Comment: Sorry, this eclipse project view is confusing to me. According to your information the resources dir is well defined. Now, do you see this `// where does the Java source code live?` comment in the build file? Put `'src/main/java'` there instead of just 'src' and check it out.

Comment: Actually you can remove the whole `sourceSets` section as you follow the standard directory layout.

Comment: To help us it would be useful if you could run `tree` command (or equivalent for your OS), from your command line. That will show us what your folder structure is and help us provide a better answer.